# Converting JSON documents to Parquet

Tags: c++, json, database, data-conversion, parquet

I hava a corpus of JSON documents and I want to convert/store them in Parquet format for efficient processing, using C++.
I have 2 questions regarding the process:

Q1- In all similar examples and tests cases that I've found online for converting data into Parquet format (such as [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/)), it seems that the schema should be defined ahead of time. However, my JSON documents do not conform to a single/fixed schema. I am just wondering if schema definition is indeed a requirement or not (as I guess Parquet is designed to support non-structured data with nesting and optional values efficiently).

Q2- Almost all the available examples are using Java libraries. However, I am looking for an efficient way to do such a conversion in C++. Any hint/suggestion for that ? (I have started looking at [Parquet-cpp repo](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp) and its test cases, but I am wondering if there is a more succinct example with minimum  dependencies available).

Answer (score 2):

A1: Parquet supports nesting and optional values, but you need to provide a schema definition in advance that specifies these nested/optional data elements.

A2: parquet-cpp is the only C++ library I know of for Parquet. Of course it is not not the only way to write Parquet - Impala, for example, implements its own Parquet stack, but you probably don't want to do that.